# NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods called infinite number of times upon insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:

Tags: database, core-data, save

[EDIT] I am changing this to more concisely explain what my problem was, after having more precisely pinpointed the issue.

I am working on core data for my app, but am stumped. It hangs in this method every time.  No crashes, no logs, no nothing.  It just hangs.

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    Section *newSection = (Section *)newObject;
    newSection.title = @"inserted";


    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}

NSManagedObject *newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

I discovered that if I put NSLogs in these two delegate methods:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

they just keep getting called infinite number of times.

Comment: Looks like it might be in your fetched results controller delegate methods (didChangeContent) what happens in there? Where does the insert method get called from?

Comment: @jrturton The only place in my code that insertNewObjectForEntityForName: is called is in the above insertNewObject: method, and I have confirmed with logs that insertNewObject: is getting called only once.  All I have in the controllerWillChangeContent: is [self.tableView beginUpdates];   also in the controllerDidChangecntent: I have only [self.tableView endUpdates];

Comment: I meet the same issue (the infinite loop). There is a cachedCellHeight transient property in my NSManagedOjbect. In my view controller, I setup the NSFetchedResultController with the tableView, and I calculate the cellHeight in the tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: and save it in the cachedCellHeight property, this cause an infinite loop! If you have the same issue, maybe you should check your codes again to find out if there is possible to cause an infinite loop (e.g. update something in NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol methods!!!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  I was creating an infinite loop.

This delegate method gets called:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

Then this eventually gets called because I called [self.tableView beginUpdates]; in the delegate method.

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
        Section *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        object.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chapter %i", indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = object.title;

    }
```

Then this delegate method:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

The the problem is that I was actually changing the NSManagedObject's attributes while it was updating the content

```
object.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chapter %i", indexPath.row];
```

this caused controllerWillChangeContent: to be called once again creating a loop that just goes round and round.

Comment: Well done! I was wondering how this one would turn out. Hope I helped with my suggestion on the delegate methods.

Comment: How did you end up fixing this? Did you manage to sort it out while still updating the managed object's attributes while it was updating the content? Or did you change the logic of your code?

Comment: by not changing "the NSManagedObject's attributes while it was updating the content"